# How to set python3.8 as the python path for the RobotFramework in Eclipse preference?

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, environment-variables, robotframework, macos-catalina

I had installed python3.8 and I can see that in Applications

[image: Python3.8 in Application list]

Verified that the path is added to the .zprofile automatically.

[image: Python3 path in zprofile file]

I had installed the robotframework and after that i had verified the locations for all of them as shown below.

[image: locations of python and robotframework]

After that i tried to configure the Robotframework environments in Eclipse >Preference i got the following error.

[image: Eclipse Preference]

But if i give usr/bin which is the path for python 2.x, it works fine.

Version details of python and Robot

[image: Versions of python and Robot]

OS - MacOS Catalina 10.15.2

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried - Go to eclipse -> window -> preference -> robot framework-> installed framework -> add python path -> apply and close

Check if this helps.

Comment: That didn't work for me. You can see the screenshot of that in my question